# Azure SignalR withAutomaticReconnect() "Error: Connection disconnected with error"... on Angular8 & Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I am using  Azure SignalR on Asp.Net Core 3.1 and Angular8. I also user withAutomaticReconnect() option on client side.  It connect with azure signalr successfully. But after some times it show this error message and connected to the WebSocket again.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your related code and tell us the Service Mode of your Azure SignalR Service?

Comment: private createConnection() {
    let accessToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${environment.client.signalr_endpoint}`, { accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();
    this.startConnection();
    this.registerEvents();
  }
  private startConnection() {
    this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
      console.log('SignalR Connected.');
    }).catch(err => {
    });
  }

Azure SignalR Service Mode: Classic

Answer (score 3):

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.'

The default [`serverTimeoutInMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/signalr/hubconnection?view=signalr-js-latest#servertimeoutinmilliseconds) value is 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds), if this timeout elapses without receiving any messages from the server, the connection will be terminated with above error.

Please check if you configured/changed [`KeepAliveInterval`option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options-1) of your SignalR hub server.

When changing `KeepAliveInterval`, we should change the `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` setting on the client side. And the recommended `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` value is double the `KeepAliveInterval` value.

For example:

*On hub server, change KeepAliveInterval to 1 minute*

```
services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
}).AddAzureSignalR();
```

*On client side, change serverTimeoutInMilliseconds to 2 minutes*

```
this.hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 120000;
```

Test Result

[image]